# Issue in updating apostrophe version 2.67.0

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am trying to update the apostrophe version from `2.62.0` to `2.67.0`.

I am getting below error:

> Promise {
>      TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined
>       at /app/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js:1085:18

While going into the file, I can see below code where error is occurred:

```
 return less.render(fs.readFileSync(src, 'utf8'), lessOptions, function(err, css) {
    if (err) {
      self.apos.utils.error('LESS CSS ERROR:');
      self.apos.utils.error(err);
    }
    css = css.css;
    if (self.apos.argv['sync-to-uploadfs']) {
      css = self.prefixCssUrlsWith(css, self.apos.attachments.uploadfs.getUrl() + '/assets/' + self.generation);
    } else if (self.apos.prefix) {
      css = self.prefixCssUrls(css);
    }
    return callback(err, css);
  });
```

Please suggest the solution for this.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this result. Please provide a test project that reproduces it. For best results it should be a simple, open source project on github with as little code as is necessary to duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have upgraded apostrophe improperly. If you were to update just that module but not its dependencies this would happen because you would have the wrong version of the `less` module.

Please update your project simply by typing `npm update`. That should update not just Apostrophe but also its dependencies.

If you continue to have trouble look at your `package.json` file and check whether you have set your own dependency on the `less` module, and an old version of it. You should not do that unless you have a specific need unrelated to Apostrophe, let Apostrophe load its own dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Tom! It was problem with `less` version that was not compatible with apostrophe version 2.70.0.